# r markdown error resulting from math in figure caption

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I had an R markdown document that was working perfectly until I added a caption with latex math. Now I get the error:

> ! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
>                   \par 
>   l.75 \end{verbatim}}
>
> pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
>   Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
>   Execution halted

The code below produces the error in Rstudio, Version 0.99.896, using knitr with pdflatex. Thanks!!

````
---
title: Title goes here
author: Names go here
date: "\today"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

Some stuff goes here

```{r ex1, echo=FALSE, fig.height=3, fig.cap="The sampling distribution of  $\\beta_1$."}
curve(dnorm(x))
```

Some more stuff goes here...
````

Comment: your caption works fine here. However, your `\today` is missing a `\` : `\\today`