# Processing of Figure Captions in R Markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

**Q:** Can anyone share (or point me to resources) on how the logical processing works for figure captions in R Markdown?

**Context:** It took me a long time to figure out how to add LaTeX math into an R Markdown figure caption (see below). I tried:

- `\frac{m}{n}`
- `$\frac{m}{n}$`
- `\(\frac{m}{m}\)`
- `\frac{m}{n}`

before finding the answer `$\\frac{m}{n}$` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216390/r-markdown-error-resulting-from-math-in-figure-caption). I looked through [this](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) resource but didn't see anything addressing this particular issue. I'm probably missing the bigger picture on how R Markdown works if it took me this long to find my answer.

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: true
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="hello $\\frac{m}{n}$"}
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Dollars are needed for latex math in pandoc markdown. `$\frac{m}{n}$` will work anywhere in the Rmd document. However, when you write some literal markdown/latex string to an R variable (which is what `fig.cap` is), you need to double all `\`